# Unity Export IOS Project

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have a problem about Unity for IOS, Details as following:
I export the IOS native project from Unity, and then I copy the project file to another IOS native project，but there were many errors，like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears these libraries are missing. Installing same version of Unity iOS should fix this. Check your project structure as well https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StructureOfXcodeProject.html Is the iOS version same on both platforms?

Edit: You are either missing some libraries required, the structure of your project is not right or you are running different versions of unit. Download and install same versions of unity on both platforms. https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download.

Test run the following code in your other IOS native project:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
    }
}
```

Share the results of above script.
Unity is supposed to be platform independent but the code may break on different versions, what unity versions are you using?

Comment: Thanks.Thanks.But I don't understand “ Installing same version of Unity iOS should fix this.”

Comment: Usually, with different unity versions, some new library is being installed or there is a different syntax to call functions. I don't know exactly the issue here. One issue that I faced while doing cross-platform development was that there was a particular graphics library in Linux which was not compatible with ray generation so I changed the version of Unity I was using for development. That fixed the problem.